# Swift: Default property vs setting in initializer

Tags: swift, methods, properties, semantics

Is there any drawback in swift to using a default property value instead of setting it in the initializer?

e.g.,

```
class Foo: UIViewController {
    let value = UIRefreshControl()
}
```

vs.

```
class Bar: UIViewController {
    var value : UIRefreshControl!

    // or using init()
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        self.value = UIRefreshControl()
    }
}
```

Default property values seem more terse and elegant, yet I don't see them used in code examples where they could be used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only downside is that default property values are set every time an instance of the object is created, even if a property is subsequently overwritten in one or more initializers. This probably isn't an issue if you're just assigning default numeric values, but if there's a class that is expensive to construct you could end up doing twice the work.

Comment: Ah, but in theory if it's a constant with `let` then this wouldn't be a concern correct? Though of course `let` with a default value would make the class less extensible...

Comment: You can actually re-assign `let`-declared properties inside an initializer. Strange but true!

Comment: Also, just want to add that I think default property values are great and I use them wherever possible. The answer is the only drawback—there are positive reasons that make them worthwhile in nearly all cases.

Comment: Interesting. `let` properties don't require a default value when set in the initializer, which for UIViewController requires tediously implementing all required initializers. Also, the default value (`UIRefreshControl()`) is always created even if `value` is set in the initializer. Lastly, using `lazy` seems the best tradeoff (if the property doesn't need to be constant) since it requires no initializers and no default property creation so long as its value is set first. (e.g., `lazy var value = UIRefreshControl()`)